# How to calculate exact number of correct answer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a exam system where i have to check, in how many subject student give the correct answer for a question but i am unable to do it. Below is my code so far i try

```
        $student=Student::find(Auth::id());
        $mark=0;
        foreach ($student->departments as $key => $department){
                $rank = new Rank;
                $rank->student_id = Auth::id();
                $rank->subject_id = $department->subject_id;
                foreach ($request->major as $key => $value) {
                $correct = Question::where('id',$key)->where('correct_ans',$value)->first();
                if ($correct)
                    $mark++;
            }
                $rank->test_id = $test->id;
                $rank->marks = $mark;
                $rank->save();
                $mark=0;
                }
```

**This code is working fine for every field but but the marks is always save as 100**. Please help me to sort it out. **And yes someone have a better idea get the correct answers please dont hesitate to share**
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing where `$major` is defined?

Comment: oopps, sorry wait for a second

Comment: `$correct` is an array, so the first time you get a correct answer, you're going to increment `$mark` every loop thereafter.

Comment: then any corrections?@aynber

Comment: yes @aynber you are correct if i remoed array sign then it will be correct but it will add all mark but i need subject wise mark like math = 48, physics =50 but here verytime i get 98

Comment: Can you give us a sneak peak of what's in`$request->major`?

Comment: i added the $request->major screenshot

Comment: thanks erveryone for your time but i fix up my issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't really judge the accuracy of the query, but if `$correct` is an array then as soon as it gets one value appended to it, it will always be true and `$mark` will increment.

If you don't need the values to access later, you can change it to:

```php
if (Question::where('id',$key)->where('correct_ans',$value)->exists()) {
```

Comment: If you don't need to hold all the correct rows, then just change it to `if (Question::where(...)->exists()) {`

Comment: Brian you could update your answer with the code fix. That will help others, otherwise it would be better to post as an comment not an answer

Comment: But the statement, if an array it will always be true is wrong. It will be true only after the first time the query returns a value. As @aynber mentioned in the comments under the question

Comment: yes it quite correct  but it will add all the marks for every subject mark but i need subject wise mark like math = 48, physics =50 but here everytime i get 98

Comment: @user3532758 you are correct, I've been writing too much JavaScript...